# Tracking 7zip progress on Windows 10 with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, ctypes, 7zip

I understand `7zip` has some issue, where it masks its progress from code that tries to call it (not sure why).

I saw [here](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/bs.htm) that `-bsp1` flag should show the hidden progress, but still nothing in Python:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from time import sleep

cmd = Popen('7z.exe e D:\stuff.rar -od:\stuff -aoa -bsp1'.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

while cmd.poll() !=0:  # Not sure this helps anything
    out = cmd.stdout.read()
    print(out)
    sleep(1)
```

Running the 7z command in the command line gives me a nice percentage until unpacking is done.

In Python, I get 7z's prelude printout (Path, Type etc.) and after that just `b''` until I press `Ctrl-c`

How does 7z know I'm calling it not from the "real" terminal? Can I somehow make it look like I am, maybe using `ctypes` and some windows kernel call / API?

I saw the term "pseudo terminal" mentioned in regards to this, but I'm not sure it's relevant, and if it is, Windows' [ConPTY](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/) API is [hidden](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewSDK)

Comment: I'm not familiar with 7zip but it's possible that you would need a pseudo-terminal. Some processes may bypass stdout and print directly to its controlling TTY. So you can't capture the output through a PIPE.

Comment: Why would they do that?

Comment: Here is a [better explanation](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/FAQ.html#whynotpipe).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to regard UNIX though I assume it's the same on Windows. 7zip is not interactive though after the command has been launched, so it's a weird choice, no? Also, when you say TTY do you just mean terminal or something else in this cotext?

Comment: I'm not experienced with Windows so I really don't know, sorry. In UNIX, a TTY just means a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `pseudo-terminal`.
I am working on windows 10.

Get the output could be easy but it is hard to get the progress immediately if you use `stdout.readline()` directly.(Because it contains `\r` and it will put the cursor in
start of the line, then `7zip` use space to fill them.).But `readline()` use `\r\n` as the seperator.

In my example, I use `stdout.read(1)` to get the output directly.
Due to the progress line is 12.So I use a number to check it.

```
import subprocess

s = "D:/7-Zip/7z.exe e E:/work/Compile/python/python_project/temp/test.zip -oE:/work/Compile/python/python_project/temp/test -aoa -bsp1"
p = subprocess.Popen(s.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
i = 0
while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    if line:
        if i == 11:
            s = b""
            while True:
                char = p.stdout.read(1)
                if char == b"E": # "Everything is ok" means end
                    break
                s += char
                if char == b"%":
                    print(s.decode("gbk"))
                    s = b""
        print(line.decode("gbk"))
        i += 1
```

This give me:
[image]

---

You could improve it:

The condition of `end`.In my code, I used `if char == b"E"`.I don't think it is good.Also if you remove the `.decode("gbk")` in each print line, you will see the file name and the number,like:

[image]

Though the char split is different from the cmd(Normally it should be `x% xx - filename`)So there is one line delay:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, interesting that 7z deletes and re-prints to the same line

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late for this question, but I have searched for an answer like [jizhihaoSAMA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11811255/jizhihaosama)  for the last 3 days I was searching this problem. It is a great answer and I just wanted to share a simpler one that I manage to produce.

So to print all the lines that `7zip` produces this simple script is enough:

```py
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    
    cmd = [r'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe', 'a', r'C:\ola\cenas.exe', "-sfx", r'C:\ola' + "\\*", '-mmt', '-mx5', "-bsp1"]
    
    final_str = ["Files read from disk:", "Archive size", "Everything is Ok"]
    
    i = 0
    with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1,
               universal_newlines=True) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            line = line.replace("\n", "")
            print(line)
```

But then maybe you don't want to see the blank lines that `7zip` output produces. In this case you have this possible code (the first three lines are always the same):

```
    i = 0
    with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            i = i + 1
            if "+" in line or i < 15 or any(s in line for s in final_str):
            
                if "Files read from disk:" in line:
                    print("\n", line)
                else:
                    print(line, end="")
```

And now because you like the the original way 7zip output looks in cmd where it prints in the same line you can use this code:

```
    i = 0
    with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1,
               universal_newlines=True) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            i = i + 1
            if "+" in line or i < 14 or any(s in line for s in final_str):
    
                if "+" in line:
                    line = line.replace("\n", "")
                    print("\r", line, end="")
                elif final_str[0] in line:
                    print("\n\n", line, end="")
                else:
                    print(line, end="")
```

The code probably can be improved but I am also no expert in python . This is my first answer so if anything is wrong just let me know :)